# how to assign all the projects to belong to user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I use devise for authentication and i have another model called project and how can i assign user to have all the projects and how can i assign as shown below?

```
user_id     project_id  role1_id  
----------  ----------  ----------
1           5           2                     
1           6           1
2           5           3
```

Comment: So you want users to be a member of x projects (a m-to-n relationship)? And you want to define  the type of membership per user (aka role)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryan Bates provided a solution on [this](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/147) thread. You can read it for full details, but it involves overriding the `current_ability` method.

```
 # in controller
def current_ability
  @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user, current_project)
end

# in Ability class
def initialize(user, project)
  if user.admin_for_project?(project)
    can :manage, :all
  else
    can :read, :all
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
has_many :project_ids, Class: 'Your Class name' ('USER' or 'WHATEVER')
```

and if u have a foreign key in your database, you can add

```
has_many :project_ids, foreign_key: 'project_id', Class: 'Your Class name' ('USER' or 'WHATEVER')
```

The above are just an example, you need to provide more details for the accurate answers. Your question and description are not enough to provide the right answers. I hope it helps....